# "Can't write; duplicate key on table" on insert / update?

Tags: innodb, mariadb

I have a strange issue with InnoDB on MariaDB.

Sometimes (and I can't reproduce it, but it happens regularly and multiple times a day on a busy server) I get this SQL error:

```
Can't write; duplicate key in table 'tablename'
```

Searching on the web, this error should be happening when creating tables, if you have constraints with the same name. But this isn't the case, since it's happening on a table during some `UPDATE` or `INSERT`. I've also checked if there are any `CONSTRAINTS` with duplicate names, but they are all different.

99% of the `INSERT`s works, 1% fails. Don't know where to start debugging.

Comment: `duplicate key` means that column(s) indexed by `primary` or `unique` index already have the same value or the same combination of values you try to insert/update. This error never happens on table creation but only when data inserted/updated.

Comment: @Kondybas what you describe is another error, like this: `Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: I recently encountered this misplaced error while migrating to the NDB engine. I had a very large INSERT statement error out with a "Duplicate key in table" message. I used a regex to split up the statement to be an INSERT statement per row, and the reported error changed to a "Duplicate entry for key" error. The second error turned out to be true.

Comment: I have updated MariaDB from 10.1 to 10.2 and the error seems to be disappeared